# Building Xamarin project

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am trying to launch my Xamarin project (which is just the base project Xamarin comes with) but boy is it a nightmare. First of all I have had the IDE00006 error which never, never seems to go away. I have tried everything and some research online has told me that I need to go back to version 23.3.0 for my NuGet packages to fix this error. And so I am trying to do so but now that wont happen as I get this error:

> Could not install package `Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 23.3.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

[image: Error message]

I don't know what to do, I feel I have tried everything. A lot of research has outdated versions of Xamarin that do not work with my situation but some has shown me that I have something wrong with my portable class libraries or something. I don't know what to do, please help.

Comment: You are trying to install a `monodroid` package into a `pcl` project. You need to only install it into your `android` project and not your whole solution.

Comment: Below is an image of VS. Are you saying that I should only click droid when i install?

http://imgur.com/a/k7d2q

Comment: You are managing packages for the whole solution. Thus it will install in every project in that solution. You can either manually only have it select droid, or to right click your droid project to make it manage packages for the droid project.

Comment: I think I got rid of that error. But now im still stuck with this error that prevents me launching my project. Is there anything I can show you so you can help me fix this issue?
http://imgur.com/a/Akcvz

Comment: Please open up a new Stack Overflow question with those errors. This is a Q&A site, not a forum. I do not see any errors in the Error List you have shown. In your next question please upload a Diagnostic Build Output.